# Как в GTK изменить выравнивание объекта?

Tags: python, python-3.x, gtk, gtk3, pygtk

RadioButtons расположены слева, а не посередине, и это нужно исправить, но я не могу понять как это сделать. Пытался искать в инете, не помогло.

Код:

```py
import gi

gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gio


class MainWindow(Gtk.Window):
    # Initializes the class and creates label + spinner
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Universal driver installer")
        self.set_border_width(10)
        self.set_default_size(400, 200)
        
        self.central_vbox = Gtk.VBox()
        self.central_text = Gtk.Label(label="Searching for drivers...")
        self.spinner = Gtk.Spinner()  # Spinner is for showing loading

        # Pushing label and spinner into the central_vbox
        self.central_vbox.pack_start(self.central_text, True, True, 0)
        self.central_vbox.pack_start(self.spinner, True, True, 0)

        self.spinner.start()

        self.add(self.central_vbox)


        driver_list = ["чус ван", "pootis man 440", "Team Fortress 2", "чус 3"]
        
        # We have a driver list so we should remove the spinner
        self.central_vbox.remove(self.spinner)

        self.central_text.set_text("мяу")

        self.driver_vbox = Gtk.VBox()
        self.central_vbox.pack_start(self.driver_vbox, True, True, 10)

        radio_group = None
        for i in driver_list:
            current_button = Gtk.RadioButton.new_with_label_from_widget(radio_group, i)
            self.driver_vbox.pack_start(current_button, True, True, 10)
            if not radio_group:
                radio_group = current_button
                    


win = MainWindow()
win.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Label нужно класть внутрь чекбокса

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После долгих и нормальных поисков я нашел метод у класса widget, который называется sethalign(). Нужно было просто добавить в цикл for
`current_button.set_halign(Gtk.Align.CENTER)`. После этого все встало посередине. Код цикла for

```py
        for i in driver_list:
            current_button = Gtk.RadioButton.new_with_label_from_widget(radio_group, i)
            current_button.set_halign(Gtk.Align.CENTER)
            self.driver_vbox.pack_start(current_button, True, True, 10)
            if not radio_group:
                radio_group = current_button
```